# Appending the index to a variable name in a loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel and Blade templates for my view. I'm writing out some data and as my columns having the same name with a number on the end I thought I could loop through them rather than write them all out.

Here's what I currently have:

I am passing an object/array called $scores:

```
<span>{{ $scores->hole1 }}</span>
<span>{{ $scores->hole2 }}</span>
<span>{{ $scores->hole3 }}</span>
<span>{{ $scores->hole4 }}</span>
<span>{{ $scores->hole5 }}</span>
```

..
etc

What I want to do is something like:

```
@for ($i = 1; $i < 19; $i++)
    <span>{{ $scores->hole . ${i} }}</span>
@endfor
```

But I just can't seem to get the syntax right for appending the index value on the end of the variable name. Is this possible to do, or am I approaching this in the wrong way?

$scores is an object I build in my controller and pass to the blade template. The data in $scores looks like this:

```
object(stdClass)[212]
  public 'id' => int 3
  public 'course_name' => string 'Golf Club A' (length=15)
  public 'played_date' => string '2014-02-05' (length=10)
  public 's_hole1' => int 5
  public 's_hole2' => int 6
  public 's_hole3' => int 4
  public 's_hole4' => int 5
  public 's_hole5' => int 6
  public 's_hole6' => int 4
  public 's_hole7' => int 4
  public 's_hole8' => int 5
  public 's_hole9' => int 4
  public 's_hole10' => int 3
  public 's_hole11' => int 5
  public 's_hole12' => int 4
  public 's_hole13' => int 5
  public 's_hole14' => int 4
  public 's_hole15' => int 3
  public 's_hole16' => int 4
  public 's_hole17' => int 3
  public 's_hole18' => int 4
  public 't_hole1' => int 4
  public 't_hole2' => int 3
  public 't_hole3' => int 5
  public 't_hole4' => int 4
  public 't_hole5' => int 4
  public 't_hole6' => int 4
  public 't_hole7' => int 4
  public 't_hole8' => int 5
  public 't_hole9' => int 4
  public 't_hole10' => int 3
  public 't_hole11' => int 5
  public 't_hole12' => int 4
  public 't_hole13' => int 5
  public 't_hole14' => int 4
  public 't_hole15' => int 3
  public 't_hole16' => int 4
  public 't_hole17' => int 3
  public 't_hole18' => int 4
```

Comment: It is possible to do, but you are almost certainly approaching it the wrong way. Why is `$scores` not an array?

Comment: Why not making the hole an array, sound wierd

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
<?php $scoresArray = (array) $scores; ?>

@for ($i = 1; $i < 19; $i++)
<span>{{ $scoresArray["hole$i"] }}</span>
@endfor
```

BTW, your approach seems wrong. Try using an array to store holes and a `@foreach` to loop. Something like this will be much more flexible for future changes

```
// Create object
$scores = (object) array(
    'id' => 3,
    'course_name' => 'Golf Club A',
    'played_date' => '2014-02-05',
    's_holes' => array(5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4),
    't_holes' => array(4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4)
);

// In your view
@foreach ($scores->s_holes as $hole => $value)
<span>Hole {{$hole}}: {{$value}}</span>
@endforeach
```

Comment: <span>{{ $scoresArray["hole$i"] }}</span> doesn't work either

Comment: Also the data inside $scores is coming from a database so I can't change the format of t_holes and s_holes

Comment: I tried myself and $scoresArray["hole$i"] is working. If the data is comming from a DB then your design is wrong. Holes should be a relationship of scores, not an attribute of it. If you prperly define the relationship both s_holes and t_holes would become an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection which is iterable like and array and my answer is still valid. For more info about DB design check https:/google.com/search?q=database+normalization